# How to make a PUT request to API through JSON with external data in body?

Tags: json, api

I'm not a coder, but I understand APIs a bit. I've been playing around the API of a marketplace I use, and I've been able to make a PUT request to the website and change the available quantity of a product I sell.

However, I would like the code to get the number of available items from a file or URL.

Right now, I can send a body like this:

```
{"available_quantity": 90}
```

But, instead of the number I would like JSON to grab a number from a local file, or an internet file. How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. You "would like JSON to". But JSON is not a program or command. It's just a data format. A way of encoding structured data. Maybe you need the `curl` command. I think it's available in most operating systems like Linux, Windows, MacOS. Or maybe download the Postman app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, probably curl is what I need. How can I do that with postman? I know how to use the app, I just need the "line of code"